# how to convert text files to pdf files without reportlab in python?

Tags: python, text, py2exe, reportlab

I have a problem when using reportlab and py2exe. It works normal on python but much error on reportlab modules when running the exe file after compiled by py2exe. Can you suggest a library or code in python way to convert a text files (with tables) to pdf format without using reportlab. Thanks.

Comment: I take it the text files are just plain text, or is there some special format strings involved?  I only ask because you mention tables.

Comment: Did you look at http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/PILAndReportlab

Answer (score 0):

I used [pyPdf](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/) in the past, which is quite good for quick and dirty solutions, though I would hesitate before using it for large projects.